# Sliding 2 divs at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am trying to slide 2 `div`s at once.

I have a `button` within a `div` that is constantly shown next to the `div`. 
And i also have a div that its hidden, `onClick` of the `button` it shows the hidden div. I have set a slide effect to the hidden `div` so it slides out `onClick` of the `button`. However the `hidden` `div` will slide out but the `button` jumps to its position.

So basically how to i make this `button` slide simultaneously with the `hidden` `div`?

here is the `jQuery`

```
$(function() {
    $('#leftmenu').hide();
});
function showLeftMenu()
{
    $('#leftmenu').show("slide",1000);

}
function hideLeftMenu()
{
    $('#leftmenu').hide("slide",1000);
}
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<div id='leftmenu' class='leftmenustyle'>

    This is my div

    <input type='button' name='Menuhide' onClick='hideLeftMenu();'>
</div>    

<div id='leftbutton'>
    <input type='button' name='menushow' onClick='showLeftMenu();'>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Create http://jsfiddle.net/ of what you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function doSlide()
  {
  $('#sidepanel').toggleClass("hidesidepanel showsidepanel", 1000);
  $('#maincontent').toggleClass("show maincontent hidemaincontent", 1000);
  $('#openmenu').toggleClass("openmenuleft openmenuright", 1000);
  }
```

Try removing any code that is un-used.

Answer (score 3):

Not so sure what exactly what you're trying to achieve, but in usual situations, this would be the solution you're looking for:

**HTML (note that I've removed the onclick attributes, as they're been handled on the JS side):**

```
<div id='leftmenu' class='leftmenustyle'>
    This is my div
    <button name='Menuhide'>Hide</button>
</div>
<div id='leftbutton'>
    <button name='menushow'>Show</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript (jQuery / jQuery UI):**

```
$(function () {
    $('#leftmenu').hide();

    $('button[name="Menuhide"]').on('click', function () {
        $('#leftmenu').hide("slide", 1000, function () {
            $('#leftbutton').show("slide", 1000);
        });
    });

    $('button[name="menushow"]').on('click', function () {
        $('#leftbutton').hide("slide", 1000, function () {
            $('#leftmenu').show("slide", 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SDtpx/1/

Comment: Hi, i have tried this piece of code and unfortunately it has not worked. Basically i am trying to slide the leftbutton div as well as the leftmenu div at the same time, at the moment the leftmenu div is sliding but the button jumps into place upon click instead of sliding out with the leftmenu div.

Comment: That's exactly what the code above is doing. Check the jsFiddle link I've posted. What's confusing here is that you're mentioning one button, when actually there are two.

Comment: I have tried the above code but it doesnt slide back in. It slides out how i want but when you click 'close' it does nothing. My other button is inside the leftmenu div so when it expands i click the button inside the leftmenu div to close it. But the same is happening it slides in then the 'slideout' button jumps back to the edge of the screen where as it should slide with the div.

Comment: That's getting way more confusing. Can you put your code into a jsFiddle and share with us? Also check for spellings. I've noticed you named the buttons in a different way (one is capitalized).

Comment: I have just copied it exactly from the jsfiddle and it is doing exactly what i want. Only my over div which contains information in the centre of the page jumps down on click but moves back into position once the div has slid out. And the same for when i close the div.

Comment: What I meant is: Place your code as it is into a new jsFiddle and share the link so we can see it working. CSS rules can affect the behavior here.

Comment: I have tried to place it in jsFiddle but it seems to not want to go how it is on my webpage, perhaps if i share a link with you? i can put it on the server as we speak

Comment: got it, check your mails

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. Here is my code.

```
function doSlide()
  {
  //$('#content').show("bounce", 1000);
  //$('#showpanel').hide();
  $('#sidepanel').toggleClass("hidesidepanel showsidepanel", 1000);
  $('#maincontent').toggleClass("show maincontent hidemaincontent", 1000);
  $('#openmenu').toggleClass("openmenuleft openmenuright", 1000);
  }
```

As you can see I have just toggled through the classes which are position in different places and added an effect to it. Thanks anyway.